# how to call jQuery(this) from anchor tag onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have

```
 <ul>
            <li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan();" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan();" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test fdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg fdg</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan();" href="javascript:void(0);">New Plan</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan();" href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
```

code and wants to add class name to a tag parrent tag li i.e. `class="selected"` bu sing jquery.
I used this jquery code

```
function setSelectedTestPlan() {
        jQuery("#tree ul li").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
        });

        jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("selected");
    }
```

But this line `jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("selected");` doesn't work...

Please help me out...

Comment: Depends on what `this` is in the function.

Comment: 'this' is the window object, debuging it would give you the answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test</a></li>
```

**js**

```
function setSelectedTestPlan(el) {      
       jQuery("#tree ul li").removeClass("selected");
       jQuery(el).closest('li').addClass("selected");
    }
```

or

**js**

```
function setSelectedTestPlan(el) { 
   jQuery(el).closest('li').addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: will this work on the right click and open a new tab or Ctrl +click (command+click). is there any other way to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the element through the function like this

**HTML**

```
onclick="setSelectedTestPlan(this);"
```

**js**

```
function setSelectedTestPlan(ele) {      
       jQuery("#tree ul li").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
        });

        jQuery(ele).closest('li').addClass("selected");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One line:

```
jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

but you will have to amend your event to pass through 'this';

```
onclick="setSelectedTestPlan(this);"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setSelectedTestPlan(e) {
    jQuery("#tree ul li").each(function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
    });

    jQuery(e).closest('li').addClass("selected");
}

 <li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test</a></li>
```

**alternative**

```
    <ul>
        <li><a class="mylink" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test</a></li>
        <li><a class="mylink" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test fdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdg fdg</a></li>
        <li><a class="mylink" href="javascript:void(0);">New Plan</a></li>
        <li><a class="mylink" href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a></li>
    </ul


$(function(){
$(".mylink").click(function(e){
     $(".mylink").parents("li").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).parents("li").addClass("selected");
     e.preventDefault();   
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<li><a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan.call(this, event);" href="javascript:void(0);">New Test</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
function setSelectedTestPlan(e) {
   jQuery(this)closest('li').addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
}
```