# call javascript function from anchor html tag

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, dom, visibility

I need to display message when the user clicks link

How can I implement something where once the user click the hyper link on Page1, a "processing..." message and then as soon as Page2 is ready it forwards to Page2?

It is working for button click which I earlier posted got response implemented successfully.Thanks.

[Hidden DOM element containing the message and to make it visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721522/hidden-dom-element-containing-the-message-and-to-make-it-visible/40721631?noredirect=1#comment68671445_40721631)

Same thing I tried to implement for the below HTML code which is using Servlet not sure how to implement

```
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/VisibilityController?searchType=workSearchDetails&workNo=<%=installAtLocListBean.getWorkNumber()%>&ID=<%= firstLocationNumber %>&sitePosition=<%=pagePosition%>"><%=installAtLocListBean.getWorkNumber()%>onclick="MyFunction();return true;"</a></td>
```

Is it possible to do as button click? Can you provide an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use either

```
<a href="javascript:someFunction()">LINK</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction(); return false;">LINK</a>
```

or you can check this link.
[anchor tag onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957320/5485645)

Comment: hey, do I have to use href = "typescript: someFunction()" if I am using typescript?

Comment: Absolute gigachad...