# Onclick event on <a> tag needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Why do I need to click twice on my "a" tag to run the onclick event?
My goal: when "a" tag clicked, display as block the div below which is hidden by default.

```js
function myFunction1(num) {
  var x = document.getElementById("description");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";;
  }
}

function myFunction2(num) {
  var x = document.getElementById("benefits");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";;
    return
  }
}

function myFunction(button) {
  var x = button.id;
  switch (x) {
    case '1':
      myFunction1(x);
      break;
    case '2':
      myFunction4(x);
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    myFunction(this);
  }
};
```

```html
<header class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a id="1">Description</a>
    <a id="2">Benefits</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="details">
  <div class="details_object" id="description" style="display: none">
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>

  </div>

  <div class="details_object" id="benefits" style="display: none">
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I also try to achieve is to only display one .details_object at a time, so if one is shown, but the other function get called, set the first one to default.

Comment: Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843494/call-javascript-function-from-anchor-html-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your html slightly so you can use the href attribute of your link and then only have one function to show and hide the relevant divs rather than a function for each link (comments in js explaining what I have done):

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('details_object'); // get all the detail divs
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); // get all the links

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { // bind your click to the buttons (pass the event into the function)
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default click event of the anchor

    for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
      if (divs[j].id === e.currentTarget.hash.substr(1)) { // compare the id of the div with the hash value of the link href (minus the #)
        divs[j].style.display = 'block'; // if they match - show the div
        buttons[j].classList.add('highlight');
      } else {
        divs[j].style.display = 'none'; // if they don't match - hide the div
        buttons[j].classList.remove('highlight');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a id="1" href="#description">Description</a>
    <a id="2" href="#benefits">Benefits</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="details">
  <div class="details_object" id="description" style="display: none">
    description
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="details_object" id="benefits" style="display: none">
    benefits
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
    <p> <span></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolorem. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing. I want to change the background and the color of the "a" tag when it's clicked. I've tried to add this piece of code after line "divs[j].style.display ='block'" :
buttons[i].classList.add('bckgrnd');

but it's not working. Do I have to create a new function for this, or I just write it at the wrong place? 
Thanks!! :)

Comment: See edit - you want to use `j` (not `i`) and the above assumes your links are in the same order as your divs, if not, you will need to loop through your buttons to remove the class and then add the class to the `currentTarget`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, again. I edited my code, but it doesn't seems to work. My link buttons and my divs are in the same order. It's not a big deal if it stays like this, just for learning purpose I'm curious what am I missing.

Comment: @Steve94Bp could you ask a new question with the new problem please so that we can see how your changed code is - it could be that you have more links - as you have used `getElementsByTagName` on the links, you may need to give the links that match up to the divs a class and use `getElemntsByClassName` (like I do for the divs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `innerHTML` property to make it more optimized and easier. You can learn more about it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```js
function myFunction1 (num) {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML= "Description paragraph";
}

function myFunction2 (num) {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML= "Benefits paragraph";    
}
function myFunction (button) {
    var x = button.id;
    switch (x) {
        case '1':
            myFunction1(x);
            break;
        case '2':
            myFunction2(x);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function (){
        myFunction (this);
    }};
```

```html
<header class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a id="1">Description</a>
        <a id="2">Benefits</a>        
    </nav> 
</header>

<div class="details">

    <div class="details_object"  id="description"/>

    <div class="details_object"  id="benefits" />
       
 </div>
```